# Using ternary comparison for property declaration only when true

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I was writing a foreach loop inside a class that checks if each item meets a certain criteria before assigning it as a property however I thought about using ternary comparison for this.

Turns out the following code works just fine:

```
$res = [];
$config = [
    'red' => 'RED', 
    'magenta' => 'MAGENTA', 
    'blue' => 'BLUE',
    'lilac' => 'LILAC'
];
$allowed = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

foreach($config as $name => $value) {
    in_array($name, $allowed) ? $res[$name] = $value:'';
}

print_r($res);
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [red] => RED
    [blue] => BLUE
)
```

Now my question is, is this a valid use of the ternary comparison? Or is this just a bug? The code looks much simpler now, however I do not want to use something that might get 'fixed' in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid code. The syntax of a ternary is:

```
<condition> ? <then-expression> : <else-expression>
```

An assignment is a type of expression, so it's allowed in `<then-expression>`. And a literal string is also a valid expression.

And any expression is allowed as a statement, so you can use a ternary without assigning the result to anything as a statement.

But I think most programmers would consider this poor style. The purpose of ternaries is to provide a concise way to use a conditional expression where you need the value, to avoid repeating the surrounding code, e.g.

```
$var = isset($var1) ? $var1 : '';
```

instead of

```
if (isset($var1)) {
    $var = $var1;
} else {
    $var = '';
}
```

If you're not using the value, there's no redundancy to avoid, so little reason to use a ternary other than trying to appear clever or save a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using just an if statement since you don't really need an else statement/block.

However if you are writing production code and everything works as it should and it passes code review (if you have those) and you provide appropriate unit tests it will probably never end up being fixed by someone else in the future

Comment: Thanks for the reply, by 'fixed' I meant that this behaviour (if it is not expected) might change in future releases of PHP.